# run() method doesn't get called from a Runnable implementation

Tags: java, java-threads

I'm having a trouble with Runnable and Thread implementations. I have this abstract class, that can not be modified:

```
abstract class Ordenador {

    ...

    protected Ordenador(String nombre, int[] array) {
        ...
    }

    protected void escribir() {
        ...
    }

    protected abstract void ordenar();

}
```

And this sort algorithm that inherit from the class above and implements the `run()` method, which call the sorting one.

```
class Burbuja extends Ordenador implements Runnable {

    protected Burbuja(String nombre, int[] array) {
        super(nombre, array);
    }

    protected void ordenar() {
        ....
    }

    public void esperar() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        this.ordenar();
    }
}
```

Finally I have my main class that creates a random array and create a new Burbuja object that sort the array. The problem is that when calling `b.join()` the array stay the same so de `ordenar()` method doesn't get called.

```
class Aplicacion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...

        Burbuja burbuja = new Burbuja("Burbuja", array);
        Thread b = new Thread(burbuja);
        ...

        try {
            b.join();
            s.join();
            ... more sorting algorithms...
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        System.out.println("");
        burbuja.escribir();   
    }
}
```

I tried modificating some parts of the code but doesn't work neither.

Comment: Do you start your threads anywhere ? i.e. do you have a all to `b.start();` ?

Comment: did you call .start() on the Thread?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `start()` method on your `thread` object

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Answer (score 1):

Your `Thread b = new Thread(burbuja);` is right, but you forget to call the start method, `b.start();`